# Beta Testing, Facebook login, Parse. Some users Facebook information is not getting saved to Parse. Swift

Tags: ios, swift, parse-platform, authentication, facebook-login

[image: parse result]
I am in beta testing and so far 5 users have complete success for login and function of the app. However 3 users Facebook information is not getting saved to Parse and the app crashes when they try to move onto the VC that loads the user profile. I don't understand what is happening. Here is my login code it will come across as very amateurish and messy so apologies up front! (Newb but trying)
App delegate:

```
import UIKit
import Bolts
import Parse
import ParseUI
import FBSDKCoreKit

@UIApplicationMain
class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate {

var window: UIWindow?

func application(application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [NSObject: AnyObject]?) -> Bool {

// code in here to check devices just left it out as it was too much information to paste.
    }

    // parse info and connection

    Parse.enableLocalDatastore()

    Parse.setApplicationId("",
        clientKey: "")


    PFFacebookUtils.initializeFacebookWithApplicationLaunchOptions(launchOptions)

    PFUser.enableAutomaticUser()

    let defaultACL = PFACL();

    defaultACL.setPublicReadAccess(true)

    PFACL.setDefaultACL(defaultACL, withAccessForCurrentUser:true)


    if application.applicationState != UIApplicationState.Background {

        let preBackgroundPush = !application.respondsToSelector("backgroundRefreshStatus")
        let oldPushHandlerOnly = !self.respondsToSelector("application:didReceiveRemoteNotification:fetchCompletionHandler:")
        var noPushPayload = false;
        if let options = launchOptions {
            noPushPayload = options[UIApplicationLaunchOptionsRemoteNotificationKey] != nil;
        }
        if (preBackgroundPush || oldPushHandlerOnly || noPushPayload) {
            PFAnalytics.trackAppOpenedWithLaunchOptions(launchOptions)
        }
    }
    if application.respondsToSelector("registerUserNotificationSettings:") {
        let userNotificationTypes: UIUserNotificationType = [UIUserNotificationType.Alert, UIUserNotificationType.Badge, UIUserNotificationType.Sound]
        let settings = UIUserNotificationSettings(forTypes: userNotificationTypes, categories: nil)
        application.registerUserNotificationSettings(settings)
        application.registerForRemoteNotifications()
    } else {
        let types: UIRemoteNotificationType = [UIRemoteNotificationType.Badge, UIRemoteNotificationType.Alert, UIRemoteNotificationType.Sound]
        application.registerForRemoteNotificationTypes(types)
    }


    return FBSDKApplicationDelegate.sharedInstance().application(application, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions: launchOptions)
}

func application(application: UIApplication, didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken deviceToken: NSData) {

    let installation = PFInstallation.currentInstallation()
    installation.setDeviceTokenFromData(deviceToken)
    installation.saveInBackground()

    PFPush.subscribeToChannelInBackground("") { (succeeded: Bool, error: NSError?) in
        if succeeded {
            print("ParseStarterProject successfully subscribed to push notifications on the broadcast channel.");
        } else {
            print("ParseStarterProject failed to subscribe to push notifications on the broadcast channel with error = %@.", error)
        }
    }
}

func application(application: UIApplication, didFailToRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithError error: NSError) {
    if error.code == 3010 {
        print("Push notifications are not supported in the iOS Simulator.")
    } else {
        print("application:didFailToRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithError: %@", error)
    }
}

func application(application: UIApplication, didReceiveRemoteNotification userInfo: [NSObject : AnyObject]) {
    PFPush.handlePush(userInfo)
    if application.applicationState == UIApplicationState.Inactive {
        PFAnalytics.trackAppOpenedWithRemoteNotificationPayload(userInfo)
    }
}

func application(application: UIApplication,
    openURL url: NSURL,
    sourceApplication: String?,
    annotation: AnyObject) -> Bool {
        return FBSDKApplicationDelegate.sharedInstance().application(application, openURL: url, sourceApplication: sourceApplication, annotation: annotation)
}

func applicationDidBecomeActive(application: UIApplication) {
    FBSDKAppEvents.activateApp()
}
}
```

View contorller:

```
import UIKit
import Parse
import FBSDKCoreKit
import FBSDKShareKit
import FBSDKLoginKit
import ParseUI

class LoginViewController: UIViewController {

var firstName: String!
var lastName: String!

@IBAction func logInWithFacebook(sender: AnyObject) {

    let permissions = ["public_profile", "email"]


    PFFacebookUtils.logInInBackgroundWithReadPermissions(permissions, block: {

        (user: PFUser?, error: NSError?) -> Void in

        if let error = error {

            print(error)

        } else {
            // user successfully signed in:


            if let user = user {
              self.performSegueWithIdentifier("registerFacebookSegue", sender: self)

            }

                }
    })


}

override func viewDidAppear(animated: Bool) {

    //to log user out

  //  PFUser.logOut()

    // segue if user is logged in:


    if let username = PFUser.currentUser()?.username {


            self.performSegueWithIdentifier("loggedInProfileSegue", sender: self)

    }


}

override func viewDidLoad() {
super.viewDidLoad()



    if(FBSDKAccessToken.currentAccessToken() != nil) {

        print("user logged in")
    } else {
        print("user not logged in")
    }
}


override func prefersStatusBarHidden() -> Bool {
    return true
}
override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
// Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}
}
```

**Got facebook passwords from a user that wasn't working and tried to log in with xcode and phone connected got this error:**

> *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'Can't use nil for keys or values on PFObject. Use NSNull for values.'
>   *** First throw call stack:
>   (0x183608f48 0x1980cbf80 0x183608e90 0x1000e49a8 0x1000e8e98 0x10012d344 0x1000e8eec 0x100062ec8 0x1000976f4 0x10009e1c0 0x10009df90 0x10009da44 0x1834ff990 0x1834ff800 0x10009d800 0x10009cd00 0x10009aed4 0x100097eb8 0x100097e10 0x100098288 0x182e9b6a8 0x182e9b638 0x182e9b7ac 0x182d074fc 0x182df5b38 0x101461c68 0x10146b40c 0x182cf3ce4 0x1834ec6cc 0x182cf3bc8 0x182cf3a88 0x182cf38b4 0x1835c0544 0x1835bffd8 0x1835bdcd8 0x1834ecca0 0x18e728088 0x188c04ffc 0x10006e488 0x19891a8b8)
>   libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException
>   (lldb)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that I was asking for email in my requests and not all facebook accounts have a. a valid email addresses and b. any email address linked at all. So I had to remove this request and ask the user to input their email address separately.